# Beans resolve to null in WebSphere 8.5.5.4

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, managed-bean, websphere-8

I'm trying to run in WebSphere 8.5.5.4 an application I've developed, that is working fine in GlassFish 4.1, but I'm facing a bunch of problems. Currently I'm stuck with one I just can't figure out a way to solve it.

In a nutshell, all my beans resolve to null, and I literally mean all. I've tried running the application without beans.xml, with beans.xml and `bean-discovery-mode="all"`, with beans.xml and `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`, with version 1.0 and with version 1.1, but the result is always the same. I already had to compromise some design decisions to make the app portable.

Some beans marked with `@Singleton` and `@Startup` where causing an exception:

> xxx can not define scope other than `@Dependent` or `@ApplicationScoped`

and marking the bean with one of the scopes didn't solve the problem:

> xxx stereotypes must declare same `@ScopeType` annotations

I really hope the community can help me to figure out the problem.

Kind regards,

Carlos Ferreira

Comment: WS 8.x is Java EE 6 implemented and ships with an ancient, bug ridden and unupgradeable MyFaces 2.0.x version. How exactly did you manage to run JSF 2.2 on that? (you tagged the question with that, which is confusing). This is absolutely not the same platform as GF4, which is Java EE 7.

Comment: @BalusC, I've installed IBM JDK 7 and created an isolated Shared Library for Mojarra 2.2 and OmniFaces. The server is JEE7 capable.

Comment: Java SE is not the same as Java EE. As to "JEE7 capable", your problem actually suggests otherwise. And, please read https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE

Comment: @BalusC, You're right, I didn't realize the server was not fully Java EE 7 compliant, my mistake. Can you please answer the question so I can accept it?